# xcode quit unexpectedly while using the DVTKit plugin

Tags: xcode

I have upgraded the RAM of my mac mini from 4GB to 6 GB, after which my machine is behaving in an unexpected manner,

1) Like Xcode is getting crashed very frequently.
2) System shut down
3) After restarting the machine, now Xcode is not launching and showing following error -

xcode quit unexpectedly while using the DVTKit plugin

the details are -

```
Process:         Xcode [427]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         6.0.1 (6528)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-6528000000000000~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [158]
Responsible:     Xcode [427]
User ID:         501

PlugIn Path:       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
PlugIn Identifier: com.apple.dt.DVTKit
PlugIn Version:    6.0.1 (6528)

Date/Time:       2014-12-24 17:05:01.324 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  B8C91A53-C5EC-FA02-FFAF-17A5CF642475


Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000032, 0x000000011059e010

kernel messages:
-0 sec              CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x11059e000): p=427[Xcode] final status 0x1000200, denying page sending SIGKILL
-0 sec              CODE SIGNING: process 427[Xcode]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x11059e000 from offset 0x316000 in file "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit" (cs_mtime:1410914376.0 == mtime:1410914376.0) (signed:0 validated:0 tainted:1 wpmapped:0 slid:0)

VM Regions Near 0x11059e010:
    __TEXT                 0000000110288000-0000000110590000 [ 3104K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
--> __DATA                 0000000110590000-0000000110653000 [  780K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
    __DATA                 0000000110653000-0000000110654000 [    4K] rw-/rwx SM=NUL  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x00007fff67d883d0 ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::rebase(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 1456
1   dyld                            0x00007fff67d80200 ImageLoader::recursiveRebase(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 126
2   dyld                            0x00007fff67d801dc ImageLoader::recursiveRebase(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 90
3   dyld                            0x00007fff67d7fa12 ImageLoader::link(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 142
4   dyld                            0x00007fff67d76764 dyld::link(ImageLoader*, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 166
5   dyld                            0x00007fff67d773ac dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 1983
6   dyld                            0x00007fff67d7327b dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 477
7   dyld                            0x00007fff67d7305e _dyld_start + 54

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000110288000  rbx: 0x0000000000000020  rcx: 0x0000000000000007  rdx: 0x0000000000000018
  rdi: 0x00000001106595a8  rsi: 0x0000000000000018  rbp: 0x00007fff4ff70280  rsp: 0x00007fff4ff701f0
   r8: 0x0000000000000001   r9: 0x0000000000000041  r10: 0x000000000000041c  r11: 0x00007fff67dc1850
  r12: 0x000000011059e010  r13: 0x00000000000002e9  r14: 0x0000000000000c3e  r15: 0x0000000110654549
  rip: 0x00007fff67d883d0  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x000000011059e010

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000006
Trap Number:     14

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 204
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=258.3M resident=162.9M(63%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=95.4M(37%)
Writable regions: Total=8572K written=44K(1%) resident=220K(3%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=8352K(97%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                           8K
__DATA                             34.2M
__IMAGE                             528K
__LINKEDIT                         74.9M
__TEXT                            183.4M
__UNICODE                           544K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             357.5M

Model: Macmini6,1, BootROM MM61.0106.B04, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 6 GB, SMC 2.7f1
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638424455302D474E2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0000, 0x5630314C3353383447423532383532383133
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x10E), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.7f3 14616, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS545050A7E362, 500.11 GB
USB Device: USB Optical Mouse
USB Device: USB Keyboard
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: iPhone
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac mini, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Now Xcode is not getting launched?